# polyglossia and and \newfontfamily\<lang>fonttt setting

Tags: fontspec, polyglossia

i'm using `beamer` with `metropolis` theme. It set `Firamono` as mono font. I'm using `polyglossia` for multilanguage documents and use `\newfontfamily\<lang>font/fontsf/fonttt` three commands to set respectively serif, sans, and mono fonts. So When I shift to the non main language with `\begin{<non main language>}`
...
`\begin{<non main language>}` I'm expecting that the three fonts are loaded. Here I'm using `verbatim` and it will use by default the mono font. Nevertheless, to get it working I need to execute `\setmonofont{<my mono font>}` before `\begin{<non main language>}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{    \usetheme{metropolis}    }

\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifontsf[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari}

\setotherlanguages{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfontsf{NotoSans}
\newfontfamily\englishfonttt{NotoSansMono}

\setmainlanguage{sanskrit}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{अ}
\begin{english}
%  \setmonofont{NotoSansMono}
  \begin{verbatim}
ṭśṣḍñ
  \end{verbatim}
\end{english}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```